# Disqus Comments Pagination

Tags: php, javascript, disqus

I have disqus comments in my webpage. I am using the below script which is given by disqus, for displaying the recent comments.

`<script type="text/javascript" src="http://prati.disqus.com/combination_widget.js?num_items=10&hide_mods=0&color=blue&default_tab=recent&excerpt_length=200"></script><a href="http://disqus.com/">Powered by Disqus</a>`

I have more than 10 comments. but I can display only 10 comments. Is there any possibility to set pagination for that to display all recent comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ravichandran, are you still looking for an answer to this problem?

Here is the html to expose a 'show all' button. Would that help?

```
<button type="button" class="dsq-button-small dsq-paginate-all-button" onclick="return DISQUS.dtpl.actions.fire('thread.paginate', 1, this, 0);">        Show all comments      </button>
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this question is really on-topic?, but...

Just log in to Disqus, go to Admin > Settings > Appearance

Scroll down and you will see options for pagination, including number of comments per page and display order.

http://disqus.com/admin/settings/appearance/

Click the link and it should prompt you to log in, and you'll land on the right page after.

Comment: That is works for comments page alone.i am searching for pagination in recent comments.